# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I tried a simple registration application in android using android studio. I am trying to make a simple database and insert values in it. I am getting the following error which i am unable to understand when i debug my app.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.
The java code goes here:

**FunTube**

Class that `get` and `set` the values

**DatabaseWrapper.java**

```
public class DatabaseWrapper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String FUNTUBE= "User";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_ID = "_id";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_UNAME = "_username";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_EMAIL = "_email";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_PASSWORD = "_password";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_FNAME="_fname";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_LNAME = "_lname";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_PHONE="_phone";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_COUNTRY = "_country";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_GENDER = "_gender";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_VIDEOPATH= "_videopath";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_BDAY = "_bday";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_YEAR = "_year";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_INTEREST = "_interest";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_RELIGION = "_religion";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_ABOUT="_about";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_QUOTE="_qoute";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_JOB = "_job";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

    }


    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FunTube.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // creation SQLite statement
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " +FUNTUBE
            + "(" + FUNTUBE_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "

            + FUNTUBE_UNAME + " text not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_EMAIL + " text not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_PASSWORD + " text not null,"
            + FUNTUBE_FNAME + " text not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_LNAME + " text not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_PHONE + " text not null,"
            + FUNTUBE_COUNTRY + " text not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_GENDER + " text not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_VIDEOPATH + " text not null,"
            + FUNTUBE_BDAY + " text not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_YEAR + " text not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_INTEREST + " text not null,"
            + FUNTUBE_RELIGION + " text not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_ABOUT + " text not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_QUOTE + " text not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_JOB+ " text not null)";




    public DatabaseWrapper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }



    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        if(newVersion>oldVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FUNTUBE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

}
```

**FunTubeOperations**

```
public class FunTubeOperations {
    private DatabaseWrapper dbHelper;
    private String[] FUNTUBE_TABLE_COLUMNS = { DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_ID, DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_UNAME,DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_EMAIL, DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_PASSWORD,DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_FNAME, DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_LNAME,DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_PHONE, DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_COUNTRY,DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_GENDER, DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_VIDEOPATH,DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_BDAY, DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_YEAR,DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_INTEREST, DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_RELIGION,DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_ABOUT, DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_QUOTE, DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_JOB};

    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public FunTubeOperations(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseWrapper(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close()
    {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public FunTube addUsers(String uname,String email,String password,String lname,String fname,String phone,String country,String gender,String videopath,String bday,String year,String interest,String religion,String about,String qoute,String job) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_UNAME, uname);
        values.put(DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_EMAIL, email);
        values.put(DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_PASSWORD, password);
        values.put(DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_FNAME, fname);
        values.put(DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_LNAME, lname);
        values.put(DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_PHONE, phone);
        values.put(DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_COUNTRY, country);
        values.put(DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_GENDER, gender);
        values.put(DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_VIDEOPATH, videopath);
        values.put(DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_BDAY, bday);
        values.put(DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_YEAR, year);
        values.put(DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_INTEREST, interest);
        values.put(DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_RELIGION, religion);
        values.put(DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_ABOUT, about);
        values.put(DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_QUOTE, qoute);
        values.put(DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_JOB, job);



        long FuntubeId = database.insert(DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE, null, values);


        Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE, FUNTUBE_TABLE_COLUMNS, DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_ID + " = " + FuntubeId, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();


        FunTube newComment = parseFunTube(cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return newComment;
    }
    private FunTube parseFunTube(Cursor cursor) {
       FunTube ft = new FunTube();
        ft .setId((cursor.getInt(0)));
        ft .setUname(cursor.getString(1));
        ft .setEmail(cursor.getString(2));
        ft .setPassword(cursor.getString(3));
        ft .setFname(cursor.getString(4));
        ft .setLname(cursor.getString(5));
        ft .setPhone(cursor.getString(6));
        ft .setCountry(cursor.getString(7));
        ft .setGender(cursor.getString(8));
        ft .setVideopath(cursor.getString(9));
        ft .setBday(cursor.getString(10));
        ft .setYear(cursor.getString(11));
        ft.setInterest(cursor.getString(12));
        ft.setReligion(cursor.getString(13));
        ft .setAbout(cursor.getString(14));
        ft .setQuote(cursor.getString(15));
        ft .setJob(cursor.getString(16));


        return ft ;
    }
}
```

**registration.java**

```
public class registeration extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FunTubeOperations FunTubeDBOperations;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registeration);
        final AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        FunTubeDBOperations = new FunTubeOperations(this);
        FunTubeDBOperations.open();

        try {
            b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {


                    EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
                    EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
                    EditText fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);
                    EditText lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname);
                    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
                    EditText country = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.country);
                    EditText phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
                    EditText bday = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bday);
                    EditText year = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.year);
                    EditText interest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.interest);
                    EditText qoute = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.qoute);
                    EditText about = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.about);
                    EditText religion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.religion);
                    EditText job = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.job);
                    RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.fm);


                    String user = username.getText().toString();
                    String em = email.getText().toString();
                    String fn = fname.getText().toString();
                    String ln = lname.getText().toString();
                    String pass = password.getText().toString();
                    String co = country.getText().toString();
                    String ph = phone.getText().toString();
                    String bd = bday.getText().toString();
                    String ye = year.getText().toString();
                    String inter = interest.getText().toString();
                    String q = qoute.getText().toString();
                    String rel = religion.getText().toString();
                    String jo = job.getText().toString();
                    String ab = about.getText().toString();
                    String gen = ((RadioButton) findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();


                    if (user != null) {
                        FunTube users = FunTubeDBOperations.addUsers(user, em, pass, ln, fn, ph, co, gen, null, bd, ye, inter, rel, ab, q, jo);
                        if (true) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (String) users.getUname() + " is added successfully!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(registeration.this, home.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Add some Data...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }


            });


        } catch (Exception e) {
            ad.setTitle("Error!");
            ad.setMessage(e.toString());
        }


    }
    protected void onResume() {
        FunTubeDBOperations.open();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        FunTubeDBOperations.close();
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Comment: on which line app is crashing??

Comment: change  cursor.moveToFirst(); to  cursor.moveToNext();  but your apprach of fetching data is not Correct .... it always return first record...

Comment: @VivekMishra it  crashes when it moves to `parsefuntube()`  function

Comment: @koutuk then what will be the correct approach!! i am a beginner to android

Comment: you want recent data to be fetched from db... or all

Comment: @koutuk It is just a simple registration form from which i am trying to fetch data from all the fields and set them

Comment: Breakpoints is your friend! Set a breakpoint to your parsefuntube() method and check. My guess is that all items do not exist!

Comment: @Paul i tried so!! but it is'nt showing me the values at this function

Comment: @tabia If youre using Android studio or Eclipse you can "Step into" your method - There should also be a tab for all local variables, including the cursor. You should be able to see if the cursor actually has 17 values.

Comment: @Paul it is displaying all data but not `_id`. while the `FuntubeId=-1` is displayed.

Comment: @tabia , it sounds to me like youve found your problem. If you are retrieving -1 of FuntubeId, it means funtubeid does not exist in that context of the db. Rewrite your cursor to retrieve the correct information.

Comment: start your cursor index from 1 instead of 0

Comment: @tabia check my answer it will work for sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its simple you have define the column `FUNTUBE_VIDEOPATH + " text not null,"` NOT NULL and you are inserting a null value from here

```
FunTube users = FunTubeDBOperations.addUsers(user, em, pass, ln, fn, ph, co, gen, null, bd, ye, inter, rel, ab, q, jo);
```

so your data not inserting to the database and returns -1 so your table dont have any data

now you are getting the data back from the db via this

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE, FUNTUBE_TABLE_COLUMNS, DatabaseWrapper.FUNTUBE_ID + " = " + FuntubeId, null, null, null, null);

cursor.moveToFirst();
```

but you are getting not data because there is no data in db

Now pass value to videopath instead of the null value and then try

eg. replace this line

```
FunTube users = FunTubeDBOperations.addUsers(user, em, pass, ln, fn, ph, co, gen, null, bd, ye, inter, rel, ab, q, jo);
```

to

```
FunTube users = FunTubeDBOperations.addUsers(user, em, pass, ln, fn, ph, co, gen,"some value", bd, ye, inter, rel, ab, q, jo);
```

it will work

let me know in case of more issue

Comment: Thankyou!! :) This was the problem

Comment: @tabia glad to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

```
// This should work
    private ArrayList<FunTube> parseFunTube(Cursor cursor) {
        ArrayList<Funtube> listofallmyFunTubes = new ArrayList<Funtube>(); 
       if (cursor != null) {
        // move cursor to first row
          if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
            FunTube ft = new FunTube();
            ft .setId((cursor.getInt(0)));
            ft .setUname(cursor.getString(1));
            ft .setEmail(cursor.getString(2));
            ft .setPassword(cursor.getString(3));
            ft .setFname(cursor.getString(4));
            ft .setLname(cursor.getString(5));
            ft .setPhone(cursor.getString(6));
            ft .setCountry(cursor.getString(7));
            ft .setGender(cursor.getString(8));
            ft .setVideopath(cursor.getString(9));
            ft .setBday(cursor.getString(10));
            ft .setYear(cursor.getString(11));
            ft.setInterest(cursor.getString(12));
            ft.setReligion(cursor.getString(13));
            ft .setAbout(cursor.getString(14));
            ft .setQuote(cursor.getString(15));
            ft .setJob(cursor.getString(16));

            listofallmyFunTubes.add(ft); 
              // move to next row
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

           }
           return listofallmyFuntubes;
    }
```